# Continue reading rows in a for loop despite of null values in a row

Tags: python, csv

I am reading csv files in a loop. The problem is there are some NUll values inserted in a csv  file, and when for loop reads those lines, it generates error.

My code is:

```
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"')
    data = StringIO.StringIO()
        for line in reader:
            data.write("\"" + str(line[i].encode('UTF-8')) + "\"")
                     .......


and the error is :
```

for line in reader:
    _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

If I use `"try and except"` , as soon as it gets Null value it enters inside 
except and does not continue reading other rows in a file. Whereas I want for loop to skip the null values and continue reading other rows in a file.

My sample data is:

```
"a";"b";"c"
 NulNulNul "f";"v";"x"
 "aaa";"fb";"a"
 "abb";"aab";"aac"
```

And i want the data after for loop to be,

```
 "a";"b";"c"
 "f";"v";"x"
 "aaa";"fb";"a"
 "abb";"aab";"aac"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reader = csv.reader( (line.replace('\0','') for line in f) , delimiter=';',quotechar = '"')
```

this removes the nuls from the lines before csv.reader gets them